# Lehmer extended GCD

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, gcd-and-lcm

There is a C-library of long arithmetic, [FLINT](http://www.flintlib.org/).
It has a function:
void fmpz_xgcd_partial ( fmpz_t co2 , fmpz_t co1 , fmpz_t r2 ,
fmpz_t r1 , const fmpz_t L ).
Here is its description from the documentation:

> This function is an implementation of Lehmer extended GCD with early termination,
>   as used in the qfb module. It terminates early when remainders fall below the specified
>   bound. The initial values r1 and r2 are treated as successive remainders in the Euclidean
>   algorithm and are replaced with the last two remainders computed. The values co1
>   and co2 are the last two cofactors and satisfy the identity co2*r1 - co1*r2 == +/-
>   r2_orig upon termination, where r2_orig is the starting value of r2 supplied, and r1
>   and r2 are the final values.

My question: how to calculate extended GCD(with Bezout coefficients) of two numbers by using this function?
Thank you!

Comment: You don't: you use `fmpz_xgcd` when you want to compute an extended GCD.

Comment: Then what is the `fmpz_xgcd_partial` for? I write my function of finding the GCD and try to take the code from the library FLINT. For a number of reasons I can not use the function `fmpz_xgcd`.